# cant upload picture using Base64 in iphone app

Tags: iphone, upload, base64

i ask this before in this forum but it was closed i dont know why, so i post my question again.
in an iphone app i have to upload a picture using Base64 encoding, but when i look in the server the picture is all white ( size = 0x0 ,54 KO ), im sure that my Base64 encode of my pic is correct because i have a php script ,i use it and the picture appear normally.
here is the php code used to upload :

```
<?php
$filename = "photo_to_upload.jpg";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$imgbinary = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$data = base64_encode($imgbinary);
fclose($handle);
?>
<img src="./<?php echo $filename ?>" />
<form action="http://host" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?php echo $data?>">
<input type="submit" value="envoyer" />
</form>
```

and the Xcode i use this :

```
 NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"photo_to_upload" ofType:@"jpg"];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]; 
 NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

 NSURLResponse* response;
 NSError* error=nil;

NSMutableData *postData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
[postData appendData:[@"data=" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[self base64forData:imageData]];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:@"HOST"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

think you for any help.

Comment: What does `size = 0x0 ,54 KO` mean? Is the size 0 bytes? What makes you think that your `base64forData:` method works correctly? Have you printed the output to the console and compared it with your PHP script? (The fact that your PHP script works doesn't verify the working of your Objective-C code)

Comment: think you for replay. 0x0 is the width x height and 54 K octet.about my base64 encode i replace the "value="<?php echo $data?>" with return value of "base64forData" function and the picture is uploaded correctly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the Content-Type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is wrong here (and that you need a Content-Disposition) but I don't know the correct values. Use Wireshark to look at the headers sent by your PHP script and use the same values in your Objective-C code.

Comment: this a part of Wireshark result :  Content-Length: 79805\r\n

Comment: sorry i cant edit the post and i copy wrong value . here is the content type captured by wireshark in php script : "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n "  is the same captured in iphone.:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I too face the same Issue **Red Mak** Answer Helped me.

**Answer That Helped**

SOLVED !!! in fact the problem was that server encode the request replacing the blanc with "+" after that it decode replacing the "+" with blanc ,but in Base64 we have allot of "+" ,the first step server do nothing( no blanc find) but in the seconde it replace the "+" and that give a wrong base64 code ,

```
to solve that i replac "+" with ASCII equivalente like this 

:[[self base64forData:imageData]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"].
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `postLength` is probably wrong (you're not showing how it was calculated and what type it is). Do this instead:

```
[request
    setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", [postData length]] 
    forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"
];
```

Comment: SOLVED !!! in fact the problem was that server encode the request replacing the blanc with "+" after that it decode replacing the "+" with blanc ,but in Base64 we have allot of "+" ,the first step server do nothing( no blanc find) but in the seconde it replace the "+" and that give a wrong base64 code , to solve that i replac "+" with ASCII equivalente like this :[[self base64forData:imageData]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"]. hope that help somone. thank you DarkDust for help ;)